# How to find predecessor in the Tree

Tags: scheme

Could you please help me with a function, I need to find the predecessor in the tree, but it returns an empty list, how to return the predecessor without using "set!"

```
(define (predecessor val  tree)
  (cond ((null? tree) (node tree)) ; If the set is null result is predecessor         
        ((> val (node tree)) (predecessor val (right-branch tree))); if val is greater  
        ((< val (node tree)) (predecessor val (left-branch tree))))) ; if val is lesser 

(define (node tree)
  (car tree))

(define (left-branch tree)
  (cadr tree))

(define (right-branch tree)
  (caddr tree)))
```

Comment: What is the data with which you are testing? And I'm not sure you can get a car of an empty list as it is done in the first cond clause.

Answer (score 0):

It returns empty list because of the base case of your recursive procedure.
The only time it exits is when `(null? tree)` is true and `tree` is what you return there.

How about this instead (untested)?

```
(define (predecessor tree val)
  (define (helper sub-tree parent)
    (cond (((= (node sub-tree) val) parent)
           ((< (node sub-tree) val) (helper (right-branch sub-tree) sub-tree))
           (else (helper (left-branch sub-tree) sub-tree)))))
  (helper tree '()))
```

It maintains the parent along with the sub-tree through each level of recursion.